# fragment conversion error in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
MyFragment frag = fragManager.findFragmentById(R.layout.testing_res);
```

`testing_res` is the layout for the hosting `Activity`. It's spitting this error at me though

> **required**: com.example.blahblah.blah.MyFragment; **found** :android.app.Fragment;

Any suggestions as to why?

Code for the fragment class

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater i, ViewGroup v, Bundle state) {
        return i.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, v, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: also tbh i'm not sure what i was supposed to pass in for the int in findFragmentById. if i'm not mistaken it's the hosting activities layout corrent?

Comment: can you post fragment java code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing following import

```
import android.app.Fragment
```

to

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Comment: my current minSdk is @ 11 i'm not using the support library

Comment: @Bryan can you post import part for `MyFragment ` and `fragManager` in activity import part